# Using ASP.NET Forms Authentication and PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, apache, postgresql, forms-authentication, npgsql

I have an ASP.NET C# WebForms application built using the following:

- Mono
- Apache
- PostgreSql
- NPGSQL
- OS Linux

Because those platforms are used a custom user/role management system was written for the application login.

One of the features we need is to redirect a visitor if they try to access a page if they have not logged in to the application.

I have been researching the [Forms Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx)

As expected almost everything I find is using the ASP.NET built-in tools that are prominently used in Windows environments. (*Which is not necessarily the case I have in my application*)

My question is can Forms Authentication be used in my scenario? Or is there another approach I could take to accomplish the same result.

PLEASE NOTE: *Before marking this as a possible duplicate question notice my environment is not the normal ASP.NET stack.*

Answer (score 0):

Using [Sessions]  is my solution.

This  [StackoverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668500/passing-session-variable-from-page-to-page#19668663) question gives a really good explanation.